# Remembering colour layout of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

Using cookies, I want it to remember the colour layout of the page. (So, if they set the gallery one color and the body background another color, it will save that on refresh. But it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if (verifier == 1) {
        $('body').css('background', $.cookie('test_cookie'));
    }

    if (verifier == 2) {
        $('#gallery').css('background', $.cookie('test_cookie'));
    }

    if (verifier == 3) {
        $('body').css('background', $.cookie('test_cookie'));
        $('#gallery').css('background', $.cookie('test_cookie'));
    }

    $('#set_cookie').click(function() {

        var color = $('#set_cookie').val();

        $.cookie('test_cookie', color);
    });

    $('#set_page').click(function() {
        $('body').css('background',  $.cookie('test_cookie'));
        var verifier = 1;
    });

    $('#set_gallery').click(function() {
        $('#gallery').css('background', $.cookie('test_cookie'));
        var verifier = 2;
    });

    $('#set_both').click(function() {
        $('body').css('background', $.cookie('test_cookie'));
        $('#gallery').css('background', $.cookie('test_cookie'));
        var verifier = 3;
    });
});
```

and my HTML:

```
<body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="media/header.png" alt="Community Header" />
            </div>

            <p>Please select a background color for either the page's background, the gallery's background, or both.</p>

            <select id="set_cookie">
                <option value="#1d375a" selected="selected">Default</option>
                <option value="black">Black</option>
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="brown">Brown</option>
                <option value="darkblue">Dark Blue</option>
                <option value="darkgreen">Dark Green</option>
                <option value="darkred">Dark Red</option>
                <option value="fuchsia">Fuchsia</option>
                <option value="green">Green</option>
                <option value="grey">Grey</option>
                <option value="#d3d3d3">Light Grey</option>
                <option value="#32cd32">Lime Green</option>
                <option value="#f8b040">Macaroni</option>
                <option value="#ff7300">Orange</option>
                <option value="pink">Pink</option>
                <option value="purple">Purple</option>
                <option value="red">Red</option>
                <option value="#0fcce0">Turquoise</option>
                <option value="white">White</option>
                <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
            </select>

            <input type="button" id="set_page" value="Page's Background" /><input type="button" id="set_gallery" value="Gallery's Background" /><input type="button" id="set_both" value="Both" />


            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here's an example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hL6Ye/

Comment: You have a better chance of getting an answer if you try a more descriptive question title and reduce the amount of unrelated code in your snippets...

Comment: @bobbymcr Okay thanks, I'll tidy it up.

Comment: Your use of "verifier" confuses me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is

```
    if (verifier == 2) {
            $('#gallery').css('background', $.cookie('test_cookie'));
        }

 $('#set_gallery').click(function() {
        $('#gallery').css('background', $.cookie('test_cookie'));
        var verifier = 2;
    });
```

in your code you are setting the **test_cookie** to the background color and the above **verifier** variable to 2.

From your code you expect **verfier** to be **2** when the page is loaded. This is not true, javascript variables are not persistent across sessions. We would not need cookies if it did, **Would we** ?.

Your approach should be two different cookies. **page_background** and **gallery_background**. When the page loads you should check the values of these cookies and set the color accordingly. If the cookies are not set, the user never bothered to save them.

Answer (score 0):

Full solution here: http://zequinha-bsb.int-domains.com/index.html

I could not make it work in jsfiddle.net

Here is a paste of it (too much, maybe):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

/* http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html */
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(-1));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = name+"="+""+expires+"; path=/";
}
/************************** quirksmode.org *****/

function setBGColor() {
    alert('Background color set!');
    var theBGColor = $("#setCookie").val();
    $('body').css('background-color',theBGColor);
    createCookie('MYSITEPGBG',theBGColor,365);
}

function setGLColor() {
    alert('Gallery background color set!');
    var theGLColor = $("#setCookie").val();
    $('#gallery').css('background-color',theGLColor);
    createCookie('MYSITEGLBG',theGLColor,365);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var bgCookie = readCookie('MYSITEPGBG');
    var glCookie = readCookie('MYSITEGLBG');
    var bgVerifier = true;
    var glVerifier = true;

    if (bgCookie != undefined) {
        bgVerifier = false;
        $('body').css('background-color',bgCookie);
    }
    if (glCookie != undefined) {
        glVerifier = false;
        $('#gallery').css('background-color',glCookie);
    }
    if (bgVerifier || glVerifier) 
        $('#giveChoices').toggle()
    else $('#allowChange').toggle();
});
```

```
</head>

<body>
<div id='gallery' style='float:left; width:400px; height:200px; display:block; ' >
    blah blah clah blah blah blah albh
</div>
<div id='giveChoices' style='display:none; ' >
    <p style='clear:both; margin-top:20px; ' >
        Please select a background color for either the page's background, the gallery's background, or both.
    </p>
    <select id="setCookie">
        <option value="#1d375a" selected="selected">Default</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="brown">Brown</option>
        <option value="darkblue">Dark Blue</option>
        <option value="darkgreen">Dark Green</option>
        <option value="darkred">Dark Red</option>
        <option value="fuchsia">Fuchsia</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="grey">Grey</option>
        <option value="#d3d3d3">Light Grey</option>
        <option value="#32cd32">Lime Green</option>
        <option value="#f8b040">Macaroni</option>
        <option value="#ff7300">Orange</option>
        <option value="pink">Pink</option>
        <option value="purple">Purple</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="#0fcce0">Turquoise</option>
        <option value="white">White</option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    </select>
    <input type='button' onclick='setBGColor(); ' value="Page's Background" />
    <input type='button' onclick='setGLColor(); ' value="Gallery's Background" />
    <input type="button" onclick='setBGColor(); setGLColor(); ' value="Both" />
</div>
<div id='allowChange' style='clear:both; float:left; display:none; '>
 <input type='button' onclick="$('#allowChange').fadeOut('slow'); $('#giveChoices').fadeIn('slow'); " value='Change Colors'  />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```